# Prevent activity from being destroyed from service

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to load an activity in a view:

```
LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();

Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);

Window w = mgr.startActivity("unique_per_activity_string", i);
View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;
```

Which seems to work perfectly. The only problem is that the activity which was loaded gets destroyed, so i cannot work with the activity.

> ** Activity (main) Create, isFirst = true **
>
> ** Activity (main) Resume **
>
> ** Activity (main) Pause, UserClosed = false **
>
> ** Activity (main) Resume **
>
> ** Service (windowservice) Create **
>
> BroadcastReceiver has been initialized.
>
> ** Service (windowservice) Start **
>   ** Activity (rammonitor) Create, isFirst = true **
>
> ** Activity (rammonitor) Resume **
>
> ** Activity (main) Pause, UserClosed = true **
>
> ** Activity (rammonitor) Pause, UserClosed = true **

The activity gets called from a Service.

Is there a way I can prevent my activity of getting destroyed, or just to keep it focused when it's created?

Comment: Note that `LocalActivityManager` is deprecated as of API Level 11.

Comment: I know, but it still works on Jelly Beans so far. The problem is that it works on a normal activity, but i'd like it to work with StandOut: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531

Comment: Anything in the logcat to indicate what the problem is?

Comment: By definition, that is not going to be possible, as StandOut windows are not activities.

Comment: There's nothing special in the logcat, perhaps this:Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@416f8550

Comment: However, note that the activity gets shown on the StandOut window, but it's get destroyed after it.